# Generate clojure spec for functions based on calls

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

Is it possible to generate/infer clojure spec based on spec for calling functions:

Let's say i have a function foo that i already wrote a spec for it, inside foo i call other function bar() that takes some of the inputs of foo (which have already spec) , so my question is it possible to infer/generate bar's spec ? Any existing library for this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so it looks like Clojure typed has what i was looking for, since i have specs for foo i can generate tests and then infer for other functions the specs and typed annotations. The utility of this since clojure is dynamic language, having already specced entry point functions we can infer sub-functions specs from those and check for consistency in code base (function called with the right args everywhere in code)

https://github.com/typedclojure/core.typed

Hope this can help others

Answer (score 2):

There is https://github.com/stathissideris/spec-provider, which you can use to infer specs at your bar's output.

I'm using this to visualize (in a pipeline) the inferred spec as shapes (in a java applet with the help of quil) and its diff between each step output compared to the anterior step (in a emacs buffer) at https://vimeo.com/240254456.

Comment: I took a look at spec provider I think if I use test generation for foo then use spec provider for functions maybe it will work to infer input for bar based on the calls. Also infer output, what you think ? Did I get it correctly ?

Comment: Thanks for making me discover `spec-provider` ! I watched also the video. Any chance to publish the code for the diff between steps ? On the other hand I find the graphical representation with shapes less useful for me (for what i can understand of it)

Comment: @marco.m Just a lot of work right now, hope to make something similar for https://github.com/pfeodrippe/clj-spec-view and you could see your data directly at the browser